# Does FFMPEG support G729 codec?

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

A bit confused here about the support of codecs with FFMPEG, does FFMPEG support any old or new versions of G729 audio codecs? If not, does this mean we have to tell FFMPEG that we have a codec and some how ask FFMPEG to support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FFMPEG Docs](http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#SEC7) state that G.729 decoding is supported, is it what you wanted to know?

Comment: Thanks...could could I have missed it :)